# problem with bib file

Tags: bibliographies

I write my report in TeXnicCenter and uses a bib file to create my references.

I have problem with creating the list of references. The error that occurs is:

```
Warning -- It didnt find a database entry
```

Adding the bib file in the tex file:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\bibliographystyle{plain}          % uses file "plain.bst"
\bibliography{References4Marsklar} % expects file
```

Below is how I write in the bib file:

```
@TECHREPORT{Anomaly detection1,
  author = {J. Ekman and A. Holst.},
  title = {Incremental stream clustering and anomaly detection},
  institution = {SICS Technical Report T2008:01},
  year = {2008},
  number = {},
  owner = {Swedish Institute of Computer Science, Kista, Sweden}
}


@PHDTHESIS{Bayesian neural network model2,
  author = {Anders Holst},
  title = {The Use of a {Bayesian} Neural Network Model for Classification Tasks},
  school = {Dept.\ of Numerical Analysis and Computing Science. 
    Royal Institute of Technology. Stockholm, Sweden.},
  year = {1997},
  pages = {16--17}
}


@ARTICLE{Metod1,
  author = {R. Steinert and D. Gillblad},
  title = {Long-Term Adaptation and Distributed Detection of Local Network Changes},
  journal = {Global Telecommunications Conference (GLOBECOM 2010). Ind.\ 
    Applic.~\& Methods Lab.\ (IAM), Swedish Inst.\ of Comput.\ Sci.\ (SICS), 
    Kista, Sweden},
  year = {2010},
  pages = {1--5},
}
```

Can you help me?
What is wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You can make the code sections of your question more easily readable by indenting them by four spaces, as I've done in the case above.

Comment: Consider reviewing the citation key requirement under [BibTeX Intro](http://bibdesk.sourceforge.net/manual/BibDesk%20Help_2.html#SEC12).

Answer (score 7):

Two comments. First, did you remember to run `latex`, then `bibtex`, then `latex` twice more? Second, you may be encountering problems because the keys of your entries contain whitespace. Do eliminate the whitespace, e.g., by replacing them with dashes, to get `Bayesian-neural-network-model2` instead of `Bayesian neural network model2`. Of course, be sure to adjust the citation commands accordingly.